# Can't rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I'm trying to migrate my database I get an error ``` Mysql2::Error: Table 'database.lorem_ipsum' doesn't exist: SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM ``lorem_ipsum ```. I've created database before by `rake db:migrate`

config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: database
  username: root
  password:
```

Comment: there is same problem

Comment: try adding socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock,  
   reconnect: true in yaml.

Comment: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database for help

Comment: Try runnig `db:schema:load`. Did you change any of the existing migrations?

Comment: and do u have gem 'mysql2' in your gemfile

Comment: I have mysql2 gem and I did not changed any migrations

Comment: Could you please paste the migration raising this issue? If it is not raised by the migration, possible reason is that you are calling LoremIpsum model somewhere in your initializers. Could you paste error backtrace?

Comment: `Table 'database.lorem_ipsum' doesn't exist: ...` why you don't run a proper migration?

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ, what do you mean "proper migration"?

Comment: mean firstly have you tun the migration, if yes show your rule to create that table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: database
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
```

On your database.yml